# dataTables header cell resize - ColReorderWithResize plugin

Tags: jquery, resize, datatables

I have a table that displays the data perfectly, but when I want to re-size the column width I click on the border/edge of the cell and it just expands the cell to random (i guess its random) width.

Also, when trying to change the width back to the original size, using mouse drag, it doesn't allow the width change to original size but instead I must re-size the other cells to get the 1st cell original width.

Is there a way to prevent the auto re-size on click but to keep the functionality to work when dragging the mouse?

The plugin used for colResize:

https://github.com/jhubble/ColReorderWithResize

Thank you

Note:
- autowdith is set to false

```
bAutoWidth: false
```

and initial width values are set with

```
aoColumns: [{'sWidth': 20% }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width % of the cells isn't calculated correctly.

Set the total (sum) of the visible cells (columns) on load to 100% (ie. you have 4 columns, each visible would be 25%)

```
aoColumns: [
    {'sWidth': '25%' },
    {'sWidth': '25%' },
    {'sWidth': '25%' },
    {'sWidth': '25%' }
]
```

That should fix your problem.